# Thin can't find pg_ext

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, thin, pg

I'm trying to run the command

```
thin -R lat.ru start
```

in the directory `50web\servers\dev` ([lat.ru](https://github.com/50pop/50web/blob/master/servers/dev/lat.ru) is part of the open source project [50web](https://github.com/50pop/50web)).

I get the following error:

```
D:\dev\derek\50web\servers\dev>thin -R lat.ru start
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': ca
nnot load such file -- 2.1/pg_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescu
e in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in
 `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/getdb.rb:11:in `<top (required)>
'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from D:/dev/derek/50web/routes/lat.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from lat.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:5
5:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:5
5:in `initialize'
        from lat.ru:1:in `new'
        from lat.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/load
er.rb:33:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/load
er.rb:33:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/
controller.rb:182:in `load_rackup_config'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/
controller.rb:72:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:20
0:in `run_command'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:15
6:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/bin/thin:6:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm using pg 0.18.4, which seems like the most recent version:

```
D:\dev\derek\50web\servers\dev>gem list pg

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

pg (0.18.4)

D:\dev\derek\50web\servers\dev>gem update pg
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Ruby version is `2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [i386-mingw32]`.

How can I fix this error?

**Update 1 (02.02.2016 08:08 MSK):**

I've to run the same project on a different machine:

```
C:\usr\dp\dev\derek\50web\servers\dev>ruby lat.ru
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.2/pg_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
```

I noticed that Ruby seems to look for the `pg_ext` file in `2.2/pg_ext` directory, whereas in reality it's installed in the `C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\pg-0.18.4\lib` directory.

[image: Location of pg_ext file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by uninstalling the pg gem and re-installing it using `gem install pg --pre` command. It's necessary because of a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issues/192/pg_ext-load-error), which hasn't been fixed in the release version yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like installation of C-extension part of `pg` gem is broken.

- make sure postgresql development libraries are installed
- reinstall `pg` gem and see if there are no error messages

Reinstallation with `-f` force flag, or better `gem uninstall` and `gem install` anew.

Comment: How do I install "postgresql development libraries"? AFAIR I tried `gem install pg-devel`, but it said there is no such gem.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Prior to gem install, there need to be postgresql libraries and header files at compilation search paths or the gem build will fail. If you are on Windows, install from available binaries [linked](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) on official PostgreSQL pages. Just checked the archive and it does contain the required development files.

Comment: How can I find out, whether development libraries are installed or not? Which files will be present in which directories, if they are?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Glad you've figured out the solution. Not aware about the bug, improper install due to missing dependencies is a more common cause. Hope you've learned something new by.